# Unity: How to upload a zip file to firebase storage without FileContentProvider?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I have a minimal working example for uploading a zip file to firebase from my Unity-Android app. The sample works fine in playing the app in the Unity-Editor mode.

However, when building for Android, I'm getting the following error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occured. (No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.MyCompany.MyApp/cache/myFile.zip)
Firesbase.Sotrage.StorageException: No content provider
```

When googling the issue, I get instructions on [how to edit a "Custom AndroidManifest.xml" and adding a FileProvider class using native Android code (by compiling a library project using Android Studio etc.](https://agrawalsuneet.github.io/blogs/native-android-image-sharing-in-unity/)).

This looks like a complete overkill for my problem. Shouldn't there be a nice and easy way to share a file, created by my app, stored in the app's own folder with firebase?

Comment: No, your app does not need a content or file provider to upload a file to firebase. You walk the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a [workaround](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory): Instead of trying to send the file directly to firebase, I can

- first read the file into RAM as a byte array
- then send the bytearray to firebase

Here some code:

```
        FirebaseStorage storage;
        StorageReference storageRef;

        storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        storageRef = storage.RootReference;

        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(localFilePath);
        StorageReference storageDataRef = storageRef.Child(firebaseFilename);
        storageDataRef.PutBytesAsync(fileData)
            .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                }
                else {
                    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and md5hash.
                    StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string md5Hash = metadata.Md5Hash;
                    Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                    Debug.Log("md5 hash = " + md5Hash);
                }
            });
```

Now I'm not getting any "FileContentProvider" errors anymore. Not sure why I have to do this though...